# Duplicate classes error after adding dialogflow dependency to my android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, dialogflow-es

I get duplicate classes error after adding dialogflow dependency to my app which uses firebase.

tried downgrading both dialogflow and firebase dependencies, also tried

```
"implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.98.0-alpha'){
     exclude group: 'com.google.api.grpc'
     exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'
}"
```

to exclude the duplicated classes. None of which worked!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.1.0'
    implementation "com.github.VaibhavLakhera:Circular-Progress-View:0.1.2"
    implementation 'com.github.CardinalNow:Android-CircleProgressIndicator:v0.2'
    implementation 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'
    implementation 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.98.0-alpha'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev145-1.25.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-dialogflow:v2-rev80-1.25.0'
    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:2.0.0-beta01"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Error:

> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0) and
>   proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar
>   (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0) 
>   Blockquote

I was able to exclude the duplicate classes with the following method:

```
android {
    ... 
    configurations { 
      implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
      implementation.exclude module:'protolite-well-known-types'
      implementation.exclude module:'guava' 
      implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-lite' 
    }
 }
```

But it caused the app to crash at launch producing this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.Preconditions"

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I'd really appreciate your input on this. any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

To exclude the duplicate classes that's causing the problem, post the following code into your build.gradle (app module) file):

```
android {
    ... 

  configurations { 
      implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
      implementation.exclude module:'protolite-well-known-types'
      implementation.exclude module:'protobuf-lite' 
  }
}
```

In my previous implementation i excluded guava module which is what caused the app crash. luckily leaving it in didn't result in any duplicate classes